# Do I need 'taint' mode for an internal website?

Tags: perl, taint

The medium-sized internal-only website that I came in to support has about 1/2 the *.cgi files without 'taint' mode.  Do I need 'taint' mode for an internal website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you *do* trust your internal users and don't *need* taint at the moment.  You could consider leaving taint ON in any existing scripts, if only to train yourself in how to use taint.  It's not as bad as it feels at first, kind of like walking on coals.  Gets better.

I can say that I've had more than one 'internal' website suddenly (requirements changed) become customer facing, exposed to the internet, and needing better security.

Another thing to keep in mind is that internal users are sometimes the most disgruntled and most likely to want to hurt your organization is some petty way.

Comment: Anything can become public facing at anytime for whatever reason. That is not a valid reason for the added labor involved in handling taint correctly in your code base.

Comment: Agreed, but it's not the only reason I gave.  The other reason was the one you gave: distrusted internal users.  I upvoted that before elaborating myself.

Answer (score 5):

Do you trust the internal users? If not, then yes.